# Python logger test by displaying on stdout

Tags: python, logging, stdout

How to print logger output onto screen(`stdout`)?

I just want to see the logs on the screen rather than open a file to check.
This is just to check my logs.

Any simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this line in code will print the logger output to screen (in **Python 3**):

```
import logging

level = logging.INFO
format = '  %(message)s'
handlers = [logging.FileHandler('filename.log'), logging.StreamHandler()]
logging.basicConfig(level = level, format = format, handlers = handlers)

logging.info('Printing on screen.')
```